# geckodriver updated to 25 still shows as 24

Tags: selenium, homebrew, geckodriver

I ran an update for my geckodriver version from 0.24 to 0.25. But when I check the version it still shows as 24. Bug?

```
/usr/local/bin Raymond$ brew reinstall geckodriver
==> Reinstalling geckodriver 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/geckodriver-0.25.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/be/beddf7cc7ac7f7c649823cef79a3e2531cfdeb35c5257e776d6a069548d29101?__gda__=exp=1568738604~hmac=e7ec584249c182d406a6df91369e45f68f7be8c6ab0e832d8e50a7b91c33bf3f&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring geckodriver-0.25.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.25.0: 7 files, 5.4MB
/usr/local/bin Raymond$ geckodriver --version
geckodriver 0.24.0
```

I'm am on a Mac.

Comment: I also checked that the path is correct .
 ```
/usr/local/bin Raymond$ which geckodriver
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
/usr/local/bin Raymond$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/geckodriver 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Raymond  admin  44 Sep 17 09:31 /usr/local/bin/geckodriver -> ../Cellar/geckodriver/0.25.0/bin/geckodriver
/usr/local/bin Raymond$
 ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the source files from `0.25.0` release, it seems they just forgot to change the version number.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/v0.25.0/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "geckodriver"
version = "0.24.0"
description = "Proxy for using WebDriver clients to interact with Gecko-based browsers."
...
```